# Reading .txt file into multiple arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to input a file that contains "1 Louise Antony 5:00". This need to be split into 3 arrays. For example, 1 should go into IDArray, Louise Antony into nameArray, and 5:00 into paceArray.

I have a code here:

```
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 25; index++) {
        infile >> IDArray[index] >> nameArray[index] >> paceArray[index];
        getline(infile, tmp);
    }
```

This code ouputs data that has not been filled. I am lost on how to go about this now.

Comment: Sorry, hopefully, this helps. It needs to be split into 3 arrays. For example, 1 should go into IDArray, Louise Antony into nameArray, and 5:00 into paceArray.

Comment: `>>` extracts a single whitespace-delimited word. So `>>` cannot be used to extract two words, like "Louise Antony", obviously, no matter how hard you try. What part of that is unclear to you?

Comment: That is what I thought afterwards, but I am unsure as to how I would go about it now? How would I input that line and divide it all up.

Comment: Don't do this. Create a *class* that holds an ID, a name, and a pace. Then create a *vector* of these objects.

Comment: You need to [specify a delimiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter) to be used in the input to tell fields apart. Depending on the delimiter chosen,  [`std::getline` may help you out.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) It defaults to using the end of line as a delimiter, but you can set any single character you want to use.

Comment: Can't believe I never thought of getline. Thanks! 

I will just manipulate the string and piece together the arrays from there!